# How to enable auto-indents in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I create a function, the line right after the function does not automatically get indented. How can I do that?

```
def test_function():
    print("I do not get an automatic indent for this line")
#When I press enter it takes me back to this spot for the previous line
```

edit (Sorry for not being clear. I am coding in python 3 and in PyCharm)

Answer (score 3):

In my version of Pycharm (2019.3.2), you can go to `File -> Settings`, search for "Smart indent", and find the corresponding check box. If you enable, it will maintain indentation after hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

---

If the search in Settings isn't working for some reason, the full path is:

> File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Smart Keys

Comment: To be specific, in the Settings, it is under: `Editor -> General -> Smart Keys`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Ya, I originally spelled out the whole path in my answer, but realized that just searching for it is significantly easier. I wish more complicated settings dialogs were like IntelliJ's. I added it back just in case though. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I actually think your answer is perfectly fine, just thought to put it out here for completeness. And yeah, I just love Pycharm!

Comment: Thanks, I checked and I do have smart indent enabled. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: That's weird. I toggled it and it's definitely responsible for that behavior. Try going to file -> invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: I did restart and it fixed it, but now I have a block cursor. Do you know how I can get the other one back?

Comment: That sounds like you accidentally hit the "insert" key on your keyboard. Try hitting "insert" again. Also, did you enable "smart indent", or "smart indent on paste" (you need the former).

Comment: I enabled smart indent, but would you know how to get rid of the block cursor that showed up when I restarted PyCharm?

Comment: Again, that sounds like you hit the "insert" key on your keyboard. Hit it again.

Comment: Ohh. Ok thank you! I didn't realize that was what you meant. Thanks

Comment: @CollinSmith I'm going to keep my answer up in case it helps anyone else. I'm honestly not sure what any other settings would contribute to this behavior unfortunately. Hopefully someone else can contribute.

Answer (score 0):

Reformat File dialog:
The dialog appears when you press **Ctrl + Alt + Shift + L** in the editor of the current file.

If you choose Code | Reformat Code from the main menu or press **Ctrl + Alt + L** , PyCharm tries to reformat the source code of the specified scope automatically.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2023.1/reformat-file-dialog.html